# What happened to git clean's --exclude-from option?

Tags: git

Back story: I have some files in various Git repos that I don't want added to the repo, but also don't want cleaned with `git clean -x`. What I *really* want is a new class of versioning in Git like GNU Arch's "precious", but failing that, I can use the `--exclude` or `-e` argument to provide ignore patterns to `git clean`. I thought I would try to write something that read the patterns from a file (like `.gitignore`) and turned each line into a `-e` argument (or the equivalent under the hood).

It turns out, someone already did that: [here's a patch to add `--exclude-from FILE` to `git clean`](https://public-inbox.org/git/1448549065-16337-1-git-send-email-rouzier@gmail.com/). The patch is discussed, everyone seems fine with it, but... evidently `git clean` does not have an `--exclude-from FILE` option as of [v2.24.2](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), even though the patch was discussed five years ago.

What happened to this idea and the patch for it? I cannot find any more information on it. Was it eventually rejected? Was it superseded by something else (something that I could use)?

Comment: You should probably ask the Git mailing list, not us. It looks like there was a discussion that just kind of petered out without a clear decision. That happens. You're welcome to get on there yourself and re-introduce it. Bonus points if you rebase it against the current version. It might get taken up.

Comment: See also https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqr3j0nsk8.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/

Comment: @VonC I got to that, it seemed to be the end of it.

Comment: @hobbs - absolutely, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't rehashing something that was already resolved!

Answer (score 2):

> I thought I would try to write something that read the patterns from a file (like `.gitignore`)

That is exactly `git ls-files`

```
git ls-files -ozi --exclude-from FILE  | xargs -0 rm
```

the `--exclude-from` is a single file, there's also `--exclude-per-directory` that also does `.gitignore`'s scoping, an `--exclude-standard` shortcut, [plus more options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Comment: This is super useful and meets my needs, and I've made an alias for it (better than my `awk` based solution for sure). But if it were first class in `git clean` you could also have eg. `-n` for dry run and other useful options, so maybe that's worth pursuing anyway.

Comment: Actually I don't think the `-i` should be there. It means it lists (and therefore deletes) files that are in my magic file rather than listing/deleting non-precious files.

Comment: Also it ignores directories. I think what is really required is `git ls-files --directory -oz --exclude-from .gitprecious | xargs -0 rm -f`. But this is the kind of thing that makes me want it as an option in the command itself...

Comment: ...`rm -fr` actually.

Comment: I don't really know what to do with these comments, they look like first-exposure-to-scripting excitement but I'm often mistaken. The point is, the general file-selection machinery is `git ls-files` and you do whatever you want with the results.   Wiring the selection machinery into every command's options processing looks like a pretty high pain/gain ratio to me, and typing `| xargs -0` doesn't seem too hard.

Comment: I'm just a little worried that someone will stumble on this answer and think it addresses the problem, when it's actually potentially destructive. More generally, I'm not super keen on piping arbitrary things through `rm -fr` without a lot of testing. Git's development has that testing regime already, as well as more structured, deliberative code behind these commands, which is why I would prefer a built-in, reviewed and tested argument to `git clean` rather than a hastily written alias.